# Soundmanager2 Loads but not playing

Tags: playback, soundmanager2

**THE SETUP**
Installed Soundmanager2 on my website.  Links to MP3s are automatically generated.

**THE PROBLEM**
Using the 360-ui, I see the sound loading because it plays the animation like in the top left of this demo (http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/360-player/), but it doesn't play and the seconds counter doesnt move.

**HOW I LOAD THE PLAYER**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/360player.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/flashblock.css" />
<!-- special IE-only canvas fix -->
<!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="/js/excanvas.compiled.js"></script><![endif]-->

<!-- Apache-licensed animation library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/berniecode-animator.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/soundmanager2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/360player.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
soundManager.setup({
  // path to directory containing SM2 SWF
  url: '/swf/',  debugMode: true 
});
</script>
```

**THE DEBUG CODE**

```
-- SoundManager 2: HTML5 support tests (/^(probably|maybe)$/i): mp3: true (preferring flash), mp4: true (preferring flash), ogg: true, wav: true -- soundmanager2.js:1155
-- SoundManager 2 V2.97a.20121104 (AS3/Flash 9) + HTML5 audio, high performance mode, normal polling, wmode: transparent, flashBlock mode -- soundmanager2.js:1155
soundManager::createMovie(): Trying to load /swf/soundmanager2_flash9_debug.swf soundmanager2.js:1155
soundManager::initMovie(): Waiting for ExternalInterface call from Flash... soundmanager2.js:1157
soundManager::externalInterfaceOK() (~2 ms) soundmanager2.js:1157
soundManager::init() soundmanager2.js:1157
soundManager: Attempting JS to Flash call... soundmanager2.js:1157
(Flash): SM2 SWF V2.97a.20121104 (AS3/Flash 9) soundmanager2.js:1157
Flash security sandbox type: remote soundmanager2.js:1157
(Flash): JS to/from Flash OK soundmanager2.js:1157
(Flash): Enabling polling, 10 ms interval soundmanager2.js:1157
-- SoundManager 2 loaded (OK) -- soundmanager2.js:1155
soundManager: Firing 1 onready() item soundmanager2.js:1157
threeSixtyPlayer.init() soundmanager2.js:1157
threeSixtyPlayer.init(): Found 5 relevant items. soundmanager2.js:1157
handleClick() soundmanager2.js:1157
soundManager.createSound(): ui360Sound0 (http://clients.activemd.net/external/x.mp3) soundmanager2.js:1155
SMSound() merged options: {
 id: ui360Sound0, 
 url: http://clients.activemd.net/external/x.mp3, 
 onplay: { pl.removeClass(this._360data.oUIBox,this._360data.className); t... }, 
 onstop: { pl.removeClass(this._360data.oUIBox,this._360data.className); t... }, 
 onpause: { pl.removeClass(this._360data.oUIBox,this._360data.className); t... }, 
 onresume: { pl.removeClass(this._360data.oUIBox,this._360data.className); t... }, 
 onfinish: { var nextLink; pl.removeClass(this._360data.oUIBox,this._360data... }, 
 onbufferchange: { if (this.isBuffering) { pl.addClass(this._360data.oUIBox,pl.css... }, 
 whileloading: { if (this.paused) { self.updatePlaying.apply(this); } }... }, 
 whileplaying: { self.updatePlaying.apply(this); this._360data.fps++; }... }, 
 useWaveformData: 0, 
 useEQData: 0, 
 usePeakData: 0, 
 autoLoad: false, 
 autoPlay: false, 
 loops: 1, 
 multiShot: true, 
 multiShotEvents: false, 
 pan: 0, 
 stream: true, 
 usePolicyFile: false, 
 volume: 100, 
 isMovieStar: false, 
 bufferTime: 3
} soundmanager2.js:1157
(Flash): SoundManager2_SMSound_AS3: Got duration: 0, autoPlay: false soundmanager2.js:1157
SMSound.play(): Attempting to load "ui360Sound0" soundmanager2.js:1155
SMSound.load(): http://clients.activemd.net/external/x.mp3 soundmanager2.js:1155
SMSound.play(): "ui360Sound0" is starting to play soundmanager2.js:1157
fanOut: ui360Sound0: http://clients.activemd.net/external/x.mp3 soundmanager2.js:1157
SMSound._onbufferchange(): 1 soundmanager2.js:1157
(Flash): start (ui360Sound0): 0 soundmanager2.js:1157
SMSound._onbufferchange(): 0 soundmanager2.js:1157
SMSound._onload(): "ui360Sound0" loaded.
```

**THE WEIRDNESS**
The links are clickable in my Chrome Developer view and the MP3 opens in a separate browser window and plays normally (default when you click on an MP3 link in Chrome)

**ONE POSSIBLE THEORY**
The sounds are being loaded, but not be told "ok, go ahead and play yourself".

**ANOTHER POSSIBLE THEORY**
jQuery is somehow screwing with it.

Please help me determine why my sounds are loading but not playing.

Thanks.
Rick

Comment: If the link is clickable but opens in another view, then add `type="audio/mp3"` to your link, so your browser recognizes it's audio

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar issue with autoplay.  It worked fine in Safari, but Chrome and FireFox, IE just traced they were playing and nothing was happening.  I ultimately put in a setTimeout to call soundManager.play(id) but I'm not enjoying I had to do that.

I notice other developers use click() events to trigger the song.  I don't know if that minor lag routing it thru a click events is what it needs to make it play or not, but I tried setting the timeout to 200 and 500+ milliseconds seemed to be the ticket.  I also figured maybe the buffering event or loading event might be able to trigger a play when the autoplay fails.  Also calling soundManager.play(id) right after soundManager.createSound(e) does absolutely nothing on my end.

I added a onbufferchange event and checked the playState.  If it wasn't playing I told it to play.  That got rid of the need for a setTimeout.